# Observer isn't notified when data has been changed

Tags: android, android-livedata, observers

I have an activity that has a SearchView that I use to enter a query, my app then uses to query to access an API. My activity further contains a fragment, and within this fragment I have my observer.

Further I have my ViewModel, which makes the API call when given a query. However, my observer is never notified about the update, and thus my view never updates. Unless I call it directly from my ViewModel upon initiation. I'll show it specifically here:

**ViewModel**

```
class SearchViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val booksResponse = MutableLiveData<MutableList<BookResponse>>()
  
    val loading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val error = MutableLiveData<String>()


    init {
    getBooks("How to talk to a widower")
    }

    fun getBooks(bookTitle: String) {
        GoogleBooksService.api.getBooks(bookTitle).enqueue(object: Callback<ResponseWrapper<BookResponse>> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseWrapper<BookResponse>>, t: Throwable) {
                onError(t.localizedMessage)
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ResponseWrapper<BookResponse>>,
                response: Response<ResponseWrapper<BookResponse>>
            ) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    val books = response.body()
                    Log.w("2.0 getFeed > ", Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                    books?.let {
//                        booksList.add(books.items)
                        booksResponse.value = books.items

                        loading.value = false
                        error.value = null
                        Log.i("Content of livedata", booksResponse.getValue().toString())
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    }

    private fun onError(message: String) {
        error.value = message
      loading.value = false
    }


}
```

**Query Submit/ Activity**

```
class NavigationActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, BooksListFragment.TouchActionDelegate {

    lateinit var searchView: SearchView

    lateinit var viewModel: SearchViewModel

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener =
        BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {R.id.navigation_search -> {
                navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(0, true, true);
                    replaceFragment(SearchListFragment.newInstance())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.navigation_books -> {
                    navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(0, true, true);
                    replaceFragment(BooksListFragment.newInstance())
                    return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
            }
            false
        }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
        replaceFragment(SearchListFragment.newInstance())
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)

        //Set action bar color
        val actionBar: ActionBar?
        actionBar = supportActionBar
        val colorDrawable = ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#FFDAEBE9"))
//        actionBar!!.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable)
//        actionBar.setTitle(("Bobs Books"))
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(0, true, true);

    }

    private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, fragment)
            .commit()
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.book_search_menu, menu)
        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this)
        searchView.queryHint = "Search for book"
        /*searchView.onActionViewExpanded()
        searchView.clearFocus()*/
//        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)


        return true
    }

    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
        //replaces fragment if in BooksListFragment when searching
        replaceFragment(SearchListFragment.newInstance())

        val toast = Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            query,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        )
        toast.show()
        searchView.setQuery("",false)
        searchView.queryHint = "Search for book"
//        viewModel.onAddBook(Book(title = query!!, rating = 5, pages = 329))
        Log.i("Query fra text field", query)
      //  viewModel.getBooks(query)
        return false
    }

    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        return false
    }



    override fun launchBookFragment(bookId: Book) {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentHolder, com.example.bobsbooks.create.BookFragment.newInstance(bookId.uid))
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
        navigationView.getMenu().setGroupCheckable(0, false, true);
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
class SearchListFragment : Fragment() {


    lateinit var viewModel: SearchViewModel
    lateinit var contentListView: SearchListView


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_list, container, false).apply {
            contentListView = this as SearchListView
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        bindViewModel()
        setContentView()
    }

    private fun setContentView(){
        contentListView.initView()
    }

   private fun bindViewModel(){
       Log.i("ViewmodelCalled", "BindViewModel has been called")
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.booksResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {list ->
           list?.let {
                Log.i("Observer gets called", "Updatelistgetscalled")
                contentListView.updateList(list)
          }
        } )

        viewModel.error.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { errorMsg ->
        })

        viewModel.loading.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { isLoading ->
        })
    }



    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): SearchListFragment {
            return SearchListFragment()
        }
    }
```

When I put the getBooks call into my Viewmodel Init, it will do everything correctly. It gets the bookresponse through the API, adds it to my LiveData and notifies my adapter.

However, if I instead delete that and call it through my Querysubmit in my Activity, it will, according to my logs, get the data and put it into my booksReponse:LiveData, but thats all it does. The observer is never notifed of this change, and thus the adapter never knows that it has new data to populate its views.

I feel like I've tried everything, I even have basically the same code working in another app, where it runs entirely in an activity instead of making the query in an activity, and rest is called in my fragment. My best guess is this has an impact, but I cant figure out how.

Comment: post your activity code also

Comment: Ive just added it, thank you for the attention!

Comment: maybe the `list` is null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your explanation

> However, if I instead delete that and call it through my Querysubmit in my Activity, it will, according to my logs, get the data and put it into my booksReponse:LiveData, but thats all it does. The observer is never notifed of this change, and thus the adapter never knows that it has new data to populate its views.

the problem is you are initializing `SearchViewModel` in both activity & fragment, so fragment doesn't have the same instance of `SearchViewModel` instead you should use shared viewmodel in fragment like :

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: The exact change ended up being: 
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)

But it worked, and you were right. Thank you so much, its beyond appreciated!